# Shouldn't motion be represented as a Taylor series rather than a finite sum of functions or a polynomial?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, fourier-transform, kinematics

Since the change in velocity of an object at rest prior to time $t_{0}$ implies a change in acceleration — that is, let's postulate, $ \mathbb{P} $, the object would have remained still, so there was no velocity change before time $t_{0}$, or put formally, $ \forall( t<t_{0} ), \| \Delta \vec{v} \| = 0 $), which implies a change in [jerk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics)), because (by the same reasoning) before time $t_{0}$ standstill requires there was no change in velocity (remember our postulate $ \mathbb{P} $), which also requires no change in acceleration, or put formally, the standstill-postulate $ \mathbb{P} \implies \forall( t<t_{0} ), \| \Delta \vec{a} \| = 0 $), but by this same reasoning, the standstill-postulate requires that there was no prior change in jerk, or put formally, the standstill-postulate $  \mathbb{P} \implies \forall( t<t_{0} ), \| \Delta \vec{j} \| = 0 $, etc., by induction we can arrive at the generalized form:

$\tiny \forall(n\in \mathbb{N}) \left [ \left ( \forall( t<t_{0} ), \| \Delta \vec{x^{\left ( n \right )}\left ( t \right )}\| = 0 \right ) \wedge \left ( \exists( t \geq t_{0} ) \exists(\nu\in\mathbb{N}) [ \vec{x^{\left ( \nu \right )}\left ( t \right )} > 0 ] \right ) \implies \forall( t\geq t_{0} )\exists(\nu \in \mathbb{N}) [ \nu = ( n + 1 ) \wedge \vec{x^{\left ( \nu \right )}\left ( t \right )} > 0 ] \right ] $

which is to say, if an object was at standstill and it obtained some motion after  $t_{0}$, this implies that for any given time-derivative its next highest time-derivative should be non-zero in view of the fact that its prior time-derivative changed some time after $t_{0}$  — but if this is correct, shouldn't that motion be represented as a Taylor series of [position](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_(vector)) functions rather than a polynomial or a finite sum of any other functions?

Comment: I understand summation of all higher order derivatives is negligible (approaching zero) for any visible macro mechanics, but I am wondering, can representing the position of particle motion as a Fourier series make a difference as we approach quantum scales?

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): For starters, a (convergent) Fourier series is a periodic function, while position does not need to be periodic.

Comment: What do you mean the acceleration "implies a cascade of higher-order position derivatives?" It is likely that $\partial_t^3x=\partial_t^4x=\cdots=0$, even if $\partial_t^2x\neq0$ (consider a particle described by the kinematic relation $x(t)=a+bt+ct^2$).

Comment: @KyleKanos By "a cascade of higher-order position derivatives", I meant a change in velocity from standstill implies a change in all other time-derivatives. Or put formally: $\small \forall(n\in \mathbb{N}) \left [ \left ( \forall( t<t_{0} ), \| \Delta \vec{x^{\left ( n \right )}\left ( t \right )}\| = 0 \right ) \wedge \left ( \exists( t \geq t_{0} )[ \vec{x^{\left ( n \right )}\left ( t \right )} > 0 ] \right ) \implies \forall( t\geq t_{0} )\exists(\nu \in \mathbb{N}) [ \nu = ( n + 1 ) \wedge \vec{x^{\left ( \nu \right )}\left ( t \right )} > 0 ] \right ] $

Comment: @Qmechanic You are right. My question is specific to bodies that are acted upon from standstill. In a sense, my question is, Why _isn't_ the position of an object initially-at-rest represented as a periodic function (perhaps a damped oscillation) rather than a non-periodic finite sum when it is acted upon (undergoes acceleration)?

Comment: I'm not getting any feedback on this. @ACuriousMind can someone please let me know how to proceed?

Comment: @MavaddatJavid revision 2 of your question [was reviewed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/70197), and the reviewers did not think your edit made it suitable to take off hold. The current version of the post should be in the queue awaiting a similar review. I'll see if any of the close voters would like to elaborate on why they hold that opinion. (Personally, I think it's not clear why you say motion is represented as a finite sum of position functions in the first place, nor why this is a problem. And IMO writing the question in formal logic doesn't help clarify it.)

Comment: The question(v4) does not make sense. The formal statement should be also expressed in natural language, since it is not obvious why it should imply that $x(t)$ should be a Fourier series rather than a Taylor series. Also, it is unclear why the "current" notion of $x(t)$ is called a *"finite sum of position functions"*.

Comment: @ACuriousMind That is helpful. Thank you. I think a Fourier series came to my mind because of its generality. But you are right that a Taylor series would be more appropriate. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7301/connection-between-fourier-transform-and-taylor-series

Comment: @DavidZ Thank you, I will also express my assertions in natural language. And I will express my question as relating to a Taylor series.

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly state the times $t$ for which some finite sum $x(t)=\sum_i^N x_i(t)$ is valid, then you avoid the issue altogether.

For example, a ball is dropped at $t=0$. I can write $y(t) = h+1/2 gt^2 $ for $t\ge0$ and be done with it.

Comment: But if the ball was at standstill, then $\forall(n\in \mathbb{N}) \left [ \forall( t<t_{0} ), \| \Delta \vec{x^{\left ( n \right )}\left ( t \right )}\| = 0 \right ] $. And if it then moves, $\exists(n\in \mathbb{N}) \left [ \exists( t \geq t_{0} )[ \vec{x^{\left ( n \right )}\left ( t \right )} > 0 ] \right ] $, which implies $\forall(n\in\mathbb{N})\forall( t\geq t_{0} )\exists(\nu \in \mathbb{N}) [ \nu = ( n + 1 ) \wedge \vec{x^{\left ( \nu \right )}\left ( t \right )} > 0 ] $ How can you merely _define_ _away_ this seemingly mathematically implied aggregation of higher-order derivatives?